# If X and Y are correlated, but Y and Z are independent, is X and Z always independent?

Tags: probability, independence

If random variables X and Y are correlated, but Y and Z are iid, is X and Z always independent? I am able to prove they are independent for specific types of structure on X and Y (for example if $X=Y+U$ where $U$ is iid), but is this true in general. Not sure why I am having such a difficult time proving the general case?

Comment: A similar question is asked at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5747, which has several useful answers.

Comment: Imagine X, Y, Z are a bunch of 3 vectors (arrows) in 3d space going from the same point. "Independent" means 90 degree angle. Any other angle is "correlated". Visualize the possibilities...

Comment: Another thread you could read is: [How can 2 variables each be strongly correlated with a 3rd variable, but uncorrelated with each other?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/83922/7290)

Comment: 1. You can't prove a negative. 2. It can be *disproven* and has been by @heropup's counterexample.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**No.**

**Counterexample:** Suppose $Y, Z \sim {\rm Bernoulli}(0.5)$ are IID.  Now let $X = YZ$.  $X$ clearly is not independent of either $Y$ or $Z$.